how to stop svg animation at the end position
If I do a simple animation of a rect in an svg, it always goes back to the beginning. How can I stop it at the end point.
  <rect class="st1" x="90" y="5" width="200" height="169">
          <animate
            attributeName="width"
            begin="0s"
            dur="12s"
            from="200"
            to="700"
            keySplines="
              0.1 0.2 0.2 1;
              0.1 0.2 0.2 1;
              0.1 0.2 0.2 1;
              0.1 0.2 0.2 1;
              0.1 0.2 0.2 1;
              0.1 0.2 0.2 1"
            keyTimes="0;0.22;0.33;0.55;0.66;0.88;1"
            calcMode="spline"
            repeatCount="1" />
        </rect>


Seems like it stops after increasing the width? Please include a [mre].

Try adding fill="freeze" to the animate
